# Configurable product listing in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product

I know how to list in Magento but I have seen sellers do this before.

I want it where there is 1 style that is available in multiple colours (configurable listing) but each colour is listed as a separate configurable listing BUT then, when a customer clicks into 1 of them, it will show all of the colour variations available. So if I had a style with 4 colour, it would show the 4 colours in the category and also when I click into one of the listings, all 4 colours in the listing.

See below an example of what I mean:

https://www.joules.com/search/?text=felicia

Can you give me some advice on how to do this? I have done as much as possible on our site by creating 2 configurable listings (BELLE RED and BELLE BLACK) and then added the other colour child products into the "Associated Products" section of each listing.

Any feedback would be hugely appreciated.